# Visibilidad de botones en java

Tags: java

hola es mi primera consulta en este portal quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer visibles botones de forma secuencial trate con un ciclo for pero no deja asi tengo mi codigo talvez hay alguien que tenga una solucion

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(+i+"  ");

    boton+i.setVisible(true);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(8000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es boton+i ? Porque no tiene forma de variable. Si lo que quieres es poder acceder secuencialmente a los botones, deberías tenerlos en un array (Button[] botones) y recorrerlos con el bucle: boton = botones[i]; boton.setVisible(true)

Comment: si perdon la idea era concatenarlos como en el  System.out.println(+i+"  ");
 pero ya veo que no se puede. Los botones ya los tengo creados seria de ingresarlos al array JButton[]?

Comment: Eso es. Necesitas algo como un array o un list para poder recorrerlos con un bucle

Comment: gracias me ayudaste un monton

Comment: Encantado. Quizás habría que poner la parte de comentarios como respuesta, para que el post quede aclarado. ¿Te parece?

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, recuerda poner una descripción del problema (qué es lo que pasa -no funciona, mensaje de error al compilar, mensaje de error al ejecutar-, que mensajes de error te muestra, etc.)